# RAID 1 Synchronization - what md1 [_U] exactly means?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, raid

I had ad HD failure in a RAID 1 configuration

- SDA is the working Hard drive (with data inside).
- SDB is the new Hard drive.

Now I copied the partition of SDA in SDB
and I need to resync the RAID but there is something strange.
From mdstat I have [_U], that should means SDA is fail and SDB is OK
How it's possible?  (see below)

It was in this way from the beginning.
Is it possible that _ is SDB???

Is it correct this procedure to set the RAID from SDA to SDB?

```
# mdadm /dev/md0 -r /dev/sdb1
# mdadm /dev/md1 -r /dev/sdb2
# mdadm /dev/md2 -r /dev/sdb3
# mdadm /dev/md3 -r /dev/sdb4
```

Thank you very much

```
[root@xyz]  cat /proc/mdstat

Personalities : [raid1]
md3 : active raid1 sda4[1]
      1847478720 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [_U]
      bitmap: 14/14 pages [56KB], 65536KB chunk

md2 : active raid1 sda3[1]
      1073610752 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [_U]
      bitmap: 8/8 pages [32KB], 65536KB chunk

md0 : active raid1 sda1[1]
      8380416 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [_U]

md1 : active raid1 sda2[1]
      523712 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [_U]
```

Comment: The `U` stands for Up in this case, a workign drive. The `_` stands for down. As you can see sda is active, sdb is down. Check the details using `mdadm --detail /dev/mdN` and include the output for at least one md. Did you manually copy it or wait for a resync after adding the new drive?

Answer (score 0):

`mdadm /dev/md0 -r /dev/sdb1` remove a device, then this missing device is represented by `_`. I would try `mdadm /dev/md0 --add /dev/sdb1` if you want to add sdb1 to the array. `--re-add` if `sdb2` has already been initialized as a part of an array.